# Enable Change tracking on all tables in a database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to enable change tracking on every table in a database.  There is a question here that shows the process

[Enable change tracking on all tables in database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28729420/enable-change-tracking-on-all-tables-in-database)

The problem, however, is that it puts GO at the end of the statement not on its own line.  I thought the char(13) and char (10) should do it. But no luck.   It creates it like this

```
PRINT 'Enable CHANGE_TRACKING on [dbo].[ReviewHistory]';ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ReviewHistory] ENABLE CHANGE_TRACKING  GO
```

Instead it SHOULD be like this

```
PRINT 'Enable CHANGE_TRACKING on [dbo].[ReviewHistory]';ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ReviewHistory] ENABLE CHANGE_TRACKING
GO
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow joey ! OK, seems like you have the solution already, then what is your actual question ?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that retain CR/LF was not enabled in SSMS options.  Once I checked that and restarted SSMS the LF was working